# Regex.Replace's pattern doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, regex

```
string pattern = ".+\\";
        foreach (string file in files){
            richTextBox2.Text += Regex.Replace(file, @pattern, String.Empty) +"\n";
        }
```

I am trying to do what should be a simple pattern match and replace, file consists of full path, for example: `d:\test\t.txt`. But everytime it crushes and says `Illegal \ at the end of the pattern.`
No joy where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash *twice*:

```
string pattern = ".+\\\\";
```

First, you need to escape it at the string processing level, so `"\\"` becomes `\` to the regex engine.

Second, the regex engine also uses backslashes for special escape sequences, so if you want to match a literal backslash with a regex, you need to use `\\`.

Since backslashes are rather common in regexes, it's usually a good idea to use verbatim strings for them (see Rahul's solution).

Comment: Bingo! When doing a regex it's best to use a verbatim string to reduce confusion. @".+\\"

Answer (score 3):

One more solution You may use `@` before strings to avoid having to escape special characters like

```
string pattern = @".+\\";
```

[CHECK MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28VS.71%29.aspx)